# Why JS map method returned this result?

Tags: javascript

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b
}

console.log(x.map(multiply))
```

**Output : [0, 2, 6, 12]**

Although, x[0] consists of value 1. Yet the output of the above code for 0th position is 0. I am unable to understand why 0 is displayed for the first position.

Comment: The same reason that the result for the 1st position is `x[1] * 1`, the 2nd position is `x[2] * 2` and the 3rd position is `x[3] * 3`...

Comment: First is current value in array secand value is index on callback function and index start with 0 hence you got this result

Answer (score 2):

Add console.log and you will see that b is the index of the array, starting with 0

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

***Syntax***

```
let new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
  // return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

In your case

```
(currentValue is a, index is b)
```

As in

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function multiply(a, b) { // better variable names  would be (item,i) 
  console.log("a",a,"b",b)
  return a * b
}

console.log(x.map(multiply))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two arguments of `.map`'s callback are the *value* being iterated over, and the *zero-indexed* index being iterated over.

The index at the first position in an array is 0:

```js
['x'].map((item, i) => {
  console.log(i);
});
```

So your code is doing:

```
[1 * 0, 2 * 1, 3 * 2, 4 * 3]
//   ^      ^      ^      ^ indicies, starting at 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mutliplying each item by their index. First index is 0 that's why first item is 0. 1*0 = 0

Answer (score 0):

when you set a function to the map method, the first argument of that function would be the values of the array and second one would be the indexes and each time you multiply value by it's index.